# limit movement of absolute position

Tags: css, css-position

I am learning to code for web development and using my personal photography website to practice. I've encountered a challenge with the positioning of a certain element that I can't find a solution for.

Here is some background information: The "body" section of the website has a minimum size of 900x600px to avoid extreme shrinking of my images. When the web browser is made smaller than the minimum dimensions specified, the overflow is hidden. At the bottom left-hand corner of the site (within in the sidebar div) there is a small div containing copyright information. I want it to display at the bottom of the sidebar and adjust its position as the window is resized to remain at the bottom of the sidebar. I have achieved this using absolute positioning. (See video for demonstration)

Here is my problem: I want that div (#copyright) to move up the sidebar as the browser window is resized, but only until it is just underneath my  menu. At that point, if the user continues to shrink the browser window, I would like the div#copyright to be hidden with the rest of the overflow of the website. The way I currently have my website configured, div#copyright continues to maintain it's absolute position, overlapping the  text.

I haven't been able to find a solution on the internet, partly because I don't know where to begin. My initial idea is to use javascript to change div#copyright's position to relative or simply to hide it when it begins to overlap the  menu. But I have to think there is a more elegant and simple CSS-only solution.

Any ideas?

Drake

Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<div id="sidebar">

    <div id="title" onclick="navigate('frameHome')">
        <span id="drake">DRAKE</span><br>WITHERS
    </div>

    <div id="contact">drake@drakewithers.com<br>(330) 690-5176<br>Athens, OH</div>

    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="sidebarHeading">PROJECTS</li>
            <li class="sidebarEntry" onclick="navigate('frameBoxcarSlideshow')">The Boxcar Studios (Slideshow)</li>
            <li class="sidebarEntry" onclick="navigate('frameBoxcarPortraits')">The Boxcar Studios (Portraits)</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="sidebarHeading">OTHER WORK</li>
            <li class="sidebarEntry" onclick="navigate('frameStreetscapes')">Streetscapes: Provo, UT</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu" id="menuAbout">
            <li class="sidebarEntry"><a href="http://drakewithers.wordpress.com" style="display:block">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarEntry" onclick="navigate('frameAbout')">About</li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <div id="copyright">
        Site under construction.<br>&copy; Drake S. Withers, 2017           
    </div>

</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
body {
width: 100%;    
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Serif';
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.5;
overflow: hidden;
min-width: 900px;
min-height: 600px;
}

#sidebar {
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 250px;
text-align: right;
}

#copyright {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 60px;
width: 200px;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 30px;
text-align: right;
border-bottom: 3px #e6e6e6 solid;
border-top: 3px #e6e6e6 solid;
}
```

Example video:
https://youtu.be/S7Ua8uatILE

Live example: 
http://drakewithers.com

Comment: You should always include code or links to fiddle / live example when asking these questions.

Comment: Thanks, Serg. I added a link to the live website; is that alright?

Comment: It's probably ok, but if you look around SO you'll notice most questions include code. Anything without code is likely to get closed. The problem is that SO is meant to be a repository of useful programming answers. If all you provide is a link to your website, eventually your website may not be online. Making this question worthless.

Comment: Thank you for the correction; just updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sidebar seems pretty consistent in its height. You could use a `max-height` media query:

```
@media(max-height: 663px) {
    #copyright {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly as well. I appreciate the response! Chosen over the other solution because of greater browser compatibility, and because I can implement it without modifying the existing layout structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but here's one.

```
#sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#copyright {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* bottom: 0px; */
    /* bottom: 0; */
    /* display: flex; */
    margin-top: auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 30px;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: 3px #e6e6e6 solid;
    border-top: 3px #e6e6e6 solid;
}
```